# How to speed up to list large data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am listing datas as below in my MVC project. But my datas are more than 10000. While filling datatable it freezes and takes too much time. I want to speed up for filling datatable.How can I do?

Controller

```
  public ActionResult ListData()
        {
            frsDTO obj = new frsDTO();
            obj.students = ent.Students.ToList();
            return View(obj);
        }
```

View

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">

                    @foreach (var item in Model.genelParametreler)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.ParametreAdi</td>
                            <td>@item.Deger</td>
                            <td>@item.Aciklama</td>
                            <td><a onclick="location.href = '/Parametre/GenelParamDuzenle?ParametreID=@item.ParametreID';" style="cursor:pointer"> <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Güncelle</a></td>
                            <td><a id="@item.ParametreID" onclick="parametreSil(@item.ParametreID)" style="cursor:pointer; color:red"><span class="fa fa-times" style="color:red"></span>Sil</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    }

            </table>
```

Comment: That is why you dont show the 10k items, you do pagination and add filter box. Who will watch 10k list anyway?

Comment: I have pagination on my datatable. But page is loading late at loading page at first.

Comment: You page it in the server, not the view!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifics for your framework, but you should look into paginating your results. This way you only load a small number of items from your database instead of 10000 at a time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination

Comment: I have pagination on my datatable. But page is loading late at loading page at first.

Comment: @james then you need to move the pagination earlier on. They need to be query parameters passed in to `public ActionResult ListData(int itemsPerPage, int pageNumber)` and the parameters used in a `obj.students = ent.Students.OrderBy(x=> x.ParametreID).Skip(itemsPerPage * pageNumber).Take(itemsPerPage);` call.